# Does GCHandle.Free() call IDisposable.Dispose()?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

Let's say I have following code:

```
public struct Test
{
   public IDisposable something;
}
```

And after allocating GCHandle and doing what I need to do with it I call GCHandle.Free(). Does this call something.Dispose() too?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/gchandle.cs

Comment: The normal state of an object is unpinned. Pinning is usually performed for a very short time and a very specific reason. It would be extremely unhelpful if unpinning an object (that is, returning it to its normal state) would also destroy it. Naturally it does not happen.